# TypeError: a float is required in python

Tags: python

```
def calculateProbability(x, mean, stdev):
    exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(stdev,2))))
    return (1 / (math.sqrt(2*math.pi) * stdev)) * exponent


exponent = math.exp(-(math.pow(x-mean,2)/(2*math.pow(stdev,2))))
```

> TypeError: a float is required

Comment: This is not complete code, include full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the three input parameters `x,mean,stdev` are `integer/float.`

It is most likely that one/more of them is not in your case.